# What is the sum of n terms 1.5.9+5.9.13+9.13.17…?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve this?
My attempt is to write the $r^{th}$ term which is $$(4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)$$
Then let $p=4r+1$
The $r^{th}$ term becomes $$(p-4)(p)(p+4)=p^3-16p$$
Now we know summation $\sum p^3 =[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]^2$ and $\sum p = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Therefore, $$\sum_{p=5}^{4n+1} (p^3-16p)$$

Is there any short method to solve it or just breaking the $r^{th}$ term into difference of two term?

Comment: good resolution. I don't think there is.

Comment: There is not enough information to determine your summation. Do you have more terms?

Comment: Hint: $\small \begin{align} & (4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)\\
= & \frac{1}{16}((4r+9)-(4r-7))(4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)\\
= & \frac{1}{16}((4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)(4r+9)- (4r-7)(4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5))
\end{align}
$

Comment: I think you have a problem in your solution.$p$ doesn't goes from 5 to $4n+1$ rather it goes $5,9,13,\cdots,4n+1$

Comment: But the index needs to be in terms of $r$, not $p$.  $p=4r+1$ will "step" be $4$.  So you need to index as $\sum\limits_{p=5;4+}^{4n+1}$ and  $\sum\limits_{p=5;4+}\ne \sum\limits_{p=5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T_r=(4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)$$ Let $$V_r=(4r-3)(4r+1)(4r+5)(4r+9), V_0=-135$$
Check that $$T_r=\frac{1}{4}[V_r-V_{r-1}]$$
Next we do telescopic summation:
$$T_1=\frac{1}{4}[V_1-V_0], T_2=\frac{1}{4}[V_2-V_1], T_3=\frac{1}{4}[V_3-V_2],.......$$ $$T_{n-1}=\frac{1}{4}[V_{n-1}-V_{n-2}], T_n=\frac{1}{4}[V_{n}-V_{n-1}].$$
Then $$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n} T_r=\frac{1}{4}[V_n-V_0]=\frac{1}{4}[(4n-3)(4n+1)(4n+5)(4n+9)+135],$$
which is a polynomial of degree 4 in $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer relies on pretty much your original method but I solved it this way.So,I thought I might just post it.
The question is to find

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (4i-3)*(4i+1)*(4i+5)$

If we expand the terms and collect terms we will get,
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}64*i^3+48*i^2-52*i-15$

$\implies 64\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3+48\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-52\sum_{i=1}^{n}i -15\sum_{i=1}^{n}1$
After that,you can just use the well known formulas for $\sum i,\sum i^2$ and $\sum i^3$

Which will lead you to,

$\implies 64(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2+48\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-52\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-15n$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general principle at work here, alluded to in the hint from @achillehui and the answer from @DrZafarAhmedDSc:

You can express $p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1)$ as a telescoping difference $H(r)-H(r-1)$ whenever $p(r)$ grows linearly with $r$. Just take
$$H(r):=p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1)p(r+2),$$
i.e., *extend the product by the next factor*. Taking this form for $H$ gives
$$\begin{aligned}
H(r)-H(r-1)&=p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1)p(r+2)-p(r-2)p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1)\\
&=p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1)\underbrace{\left[p(r+2)-p(r-2)\right]}_k\end{aligned}
$$
where $k$ is a constant free of $r$. In your case $p(r):=4r+1$, so $k=16$. Sum from $r=1$ to $r=n$ to obtain
$$
H(n)-H(0)=k\sum_{r=1}^n p(r-1)p(r)p(r+1).
$$